# Azure Queue Async Messages

Tags: azure, azure-storage

We are thinking of speparate Queues for:

> 1. Request (RequestQueue)
> 2. Response (ResponseQueue)

Scenario:

> 1. Worker role will putMessage to RequestQueue e.g. GetOrders
> 2. Third party will monitor RequestQueue. If they see GetOrders
>      request they will getMessage, process them and put the response in
>      ResponseQueue.

Question:
If I putMessage to RequestQueue, I will like to get results back from ResponseQueue. Is there easy way to achieve this and how?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible.  If you put a message in a queue, you must pop the message from the same queue (it will not magically appear in any other queue).  Perhaps if you explained more why you think you need two separate queues here for push/pop, there might be a more expansive answer and suggestion.

EDIT:  Perhaps I misunderstood your intent.  I guess I don't get the question now - can you help clarify.  You seem to be asking how to put a message on one queue, acknowledge it by putting another message on another queue, and have someone read the acknowledgment from the second queue?  What is the question here?  I should point out that you won't want some 3rd party to read directly from a Windows Azure queue as that would require sharing the master storage key with them (a non-starter).  Perhaps you are looking for how to have 3rd parties read from a queue?

EDIT 2: Sounds like you want to consume messages with a 3rd Party.  Windows Azure queues probably are not a good fit as I mentioned due to security reasons (you need to share the master key).  Instead, you could either layer a WCF service over the queue (using queues via proxy) or use the queueing from the Service Bus - that will allow you to have separate credentials.  Using the Service Bus capability might be the right choice here in terms of simplicity.  Take a look [here](http://appfabricdemos.codeplex.com/releases/view/66502) for demos.

Comment: I *think* you misunderstood. I think flybyte wants to put questions on one queue and then read the answers from another queue.

Comment: Yep, thanks guys. I want to put in RequestQueue. THird party pickups the request and put on to ResponseQueue. I want to pick up the ResponseQueue.

Comment: And the proper way of doing that is exposing the queue through a WCF service, IMHO. You can do custom authentication, and read any queue you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

Have a worker of some sort monitor the question queue, then post an answer to the answer queue. Interface out the queue managers and you shouldn't have any problems using any sort of queue tech. Also, the worker doesn't really need to use a queue for answers..

Caveats:

1. Worker service has access to both queues
2. Each queue item contains a serialized foreign key to identify themselves.